# How to create a non-random subscription with PusubIO?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using google dataflow and pubsubIO to receive a stream of various information from another app. Currently the pipeline creates a random subscription to the topic and then receives the information from here. I was wondering if there was a way to create a non-random subscription within my pubsubIO?

I know you can create a subscription in the cloud console and then sub from there using fromSubscription(), but I wanted to know if my app could create the subscription that subscribes the the topic without having to create it beforehand.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by random and non-random? The Pub/Sub subscription must exist before the pipeline is executed. It can be created manually or by the application itself.

Comment: Currently my pipeline is creating a random subscription to the topic. Upon pipeline creation, the console displays:

    "Mar 06, 2018 9:40:52 AM 
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource 
    createRandomSubscription"

I am looking to create the subscription myself in my application.

Comment: Do you happen to be using code from this repo?
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubUnboundedSource.java

If so I can see from the GitHub repo that the method split(desiredNumSplits, PielineOptions) creates a random subscription when the subscription path is null.
The method createReader( options, checkpoint ) creates a random subscription when the checkpoint is null.

Are you using this methods with any of the aforementioned parameters with  null value?

Comment: Paula - these are implementation detail methods and a user never invokes them directly, only via PubsubIO. To the author's original question: this is not possible with PubsubIO (though you can certainly call the Pubsub API yourself to create the subscription in your main() method before starting the pipeline), could you elaborate why you need this?

Comment: Hey Paula, I am using code from that repo. I am not using that method specifically, but I am trying to use creatSubscription(topic, subscription, ackDeadlineSecond). So it very well might be a null value being passed through and it then creating a random subscription.

Comment: @jkff that is indeed what I am trying to do, but am having trouble figuring out how to specify the subscription before the pipeline is created.

Comment: @jkff I need this because I want to have 1 individual subscription that my application uses. Having multiple subscriptions created at random whenever my app starts up seems to cause me to lose and data that was waiting while my app is off.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries has an example of using the Pubsub client from Java. http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/SubscriptionAdminClient.html is the class you need and it has an example of creating a subscription.

Comment: @jkff Thanks for the references, I have found them a little while ago and am now testing them to see if they function how I like. Thanks for the help!